# Bit circular shift just shows a bunch of zeros

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

I wanted to play around with bitwise operators and specifically wanted to make a circular bitwise shift. So say that I have the number `101`. Shifting it left 1 step should result in `011`. Now when I try this example in Java, it just shows a bunch of zeros, like this:

```
//Circular right shift
private static void testCircular() {
    int x = 37;
    System.out.println(x + " Is " + Integer.toBinaryString(x));

    x = (x >>> 8) | (x << (Integer.SIZE - 8));

    System.out.println(x + " Is " + Integer.toBinaryString(x));
}
```

This gives me the following result:

```
37 Is 100101
620756992 Is 100101000000000000000000000000
```

As you can see, it merly added trailing zeroes, not shifting anything. I also tried the `state = Integer.rotateRight(state,8);` method, it does the same thing. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it works as expected, what You are missing is full representation of number in bits - when You print it's skipping zeros at the beginning. Integer is stored in 32 bits, so full representation looks like this:

```
int x = 37;
00000000000000000000000000100101

x = (x >>> 8) | (x << (Integer.SIZE - 8));
00100101000000000000000000000000
```

**EDIT**

Here is a method to get a full string representation of an Integer:

```
public static String toBinaryStringWithLeadingZeros(int x) {
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(32);
    char[] arr = new char[Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(x)];
    Arrays.fill(arr, '0');
    buf.append(arr);
    buf.append(Integer.toBinaryString(x));
    return buf.toString();
}
```

Comment: This is definitely the correct answer. Easy way to test it is by shift '37' 32 times and you will get the original '37'.

Comment: I see, isn't it a little misleading that the binary string doesn't print all the zeroes?

Comment: For my taste it might be misleading, i even check if there is an option to print full representation but i couldn't find one.

Comment: One option is to use Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(x) to check the number of leading zeros and write Your own print method.

Answer (score 0):

Your code and `Integer.rotateRight(state,8);` give the same result and work as expected. `int`in java is 4 bytes so `100101` is actually:

```
00000000000000000000000000100101
```

When you shift rotate it right 8 times you get:

```
00100101000000000000000000000000
```

`Integer.toBinaryString(x))` discards leading zeros so what you see is `100101` in the first case and `100101000000000000000000000000`in the second (first two zeros are discarded).